# Visual C++ preprocessor definitions

Tags: visual-c++, preprocessor, command-line-arguments, custom-build-step

Is there a way to transfer C++ preprocessor definitions into a custom pre-link step procedure call as a command-line parameter or export them into a file any other way?
Example:
Let's say, I have a c++ project, and in it's Debug configuration I put a preprocessor definition like MAKUMBA_OBA=0x13
Then I add custom pre-link step which executes some javascript like

```
sarahjessicaparker.js /to tomsrhinoplasty $(MAKUMBA_OBA)
```

It would be great, if it just worked, but I never get a third parameter in my js. So the question is: how to pass a preprocessor definition to s script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do such a thing. The only acceptable solution is to analyze the build profile name and act accordingly.